# {nativescript} + {wordpress} : insert post using wp-rest-api

Tags: wordpress, nativescript

I'm building mobile application with nativescript and wordpress. I want to update post on wordpress using wp-rest-api. I'm following guide [here](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/). My code as below. I think I'm missing login syntaks, please help

```
exports.signUp = function(args) {
    fetch("http://kcdm.my.id/wp-json/wp/v2/sales", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({username: "sa-kcdm", firstname: "aaa", lastname: "bbb"}),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            alert({title: "POST Response", message: JSON.stringify(response), okButtonText: "Close"});
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        })
}
```

[image: error log on nativescript]

Comment: Could you provide more info about the problem you have.

Comment: i want to update my post on wordpress. one solution is using wp rest api. above is my code for update post but i think it failed because of login not yet auhtenticate. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/67206431?noredirect=1) is my another question about how to using base64 in nativescript, but it's error because all module base64 using buffer. :(

Comment: To be able to create new post you should also add credentials, which authorizes that you have permission for this operation. Your header should also include 'Authorization' string. Example `headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", "Authorization":"Basic"+ <authorization_string>
        }`

Comment: many thanks @NikolayTsonev, yours answer enlightening me :)